Prove that a triangle with bisectral triangle being a right triangle always has a 120-degree angle
Given a triangle $ABC$ with its angle bisectors $AA_1$, $BB_1$, and $CC_1$ intersecting at point $I$, and angle $\angle A_1C_1B_1 = 90^\circ$, prove that angle $\angle ACB=120^\circ$.

This turned out to be a truly interesting problem to solve using only elementary geometry.
After tinkering with this problem for long enough, my only thought was to somehow use that points $A_1$, $B_1$, and $C_1$ are on one circle with $A_1B_1$ being its diameter.
To mention, the converse of this problem has plenty of known solutions. However, this one is way harder to solve with elementary geometry.
A construction of equilateral triangle somewhere may also help because we're talking about 120 degree angle, and that is the exterior angle of such triangle.
The elementary proof I know for the converse theorem is the following:

We are given $\angle ACB = 120^\circ$ and we need to prove $\angle A_1C_1B_1=90^\circ$.
Observe that in triangle $_\Delta ACC_1$, point $A_1$ is the point of intersection of interior angle bisector $AI$ and exterior angle bisector $CD$.
Therefore, as any two exterior angle bisectors of a triangle are concurrent (as discussed here), $C_1A_1$ is an exterior angle bisector of triangle $_\Delta ACC_1$, hence $\angle A_1C_1C = \angle A_1C_1B$.
Apply the same reasoning to point $B_1$ and triangle $_\Delta BCC_1$ to conclude $\angle B_1C_1C=\angle B_1C_1A$.
The required result is now following immediately from Bisectors of Adjacent Angles between Straight Lines Meeting at Point are Perpendicular.


In geometry, the converse proof can often be hacked to lead to a solution. EG In the attached pdf, the fourth method obviously works both ways, which they also stated. Thought it uses trigonometry, and I'm uncertain if OP considers it not "elementary geometry" (which is a bit vague in its meaning)

@CalvinLin By 'elementary geometry' I mean the one in Euclid's Elements, no trigonometry, and preferrably no triangle similarity. Pretty sure this is possible. I know an elementary geometry proof of the straight theorem, not included in that paper, if that's of any interest, and I'm looking for a similar proof for converse one.

Can you share your elementary proof of the straight theorem that's not in the paper? That would help demonstrate that you've been working on this problem.

@Rusurano: Elements establishes and uses similarity from book 5 onwards, many would consider its use also elementary

@CalvinLin Done.

@RobinSparrow True, though I'm curious whether the similarity is absolutely necessary to prove the required result, as for the converse theorem it's not.

FYI Your approach is their third method.

In case anyone was wondering, we have generally
$$\cos\angle B_1A_1C_1=\frac{1 + 2 \cos A}{
\sqrt{
\left(1+8\cos\tfrac12A\cos\tfrac12B\sin\tfrac12C\right)
\left(1+8\cos\tfrac12A\sin\tfrac12B\cos\tfrac12C\right)
}}$$
So, $A=120^\circ$ iff $\angle B_1A_1C_1=90^\circ$ is clear. Perhaps this can inform an "elementary geometry" solution.

Please, in your title, change "bisectral triangle" into "incentral triangle" which is the commonly used word for the triangle of the feet of angle bissectors.

@Blue Very interesting. Please make an answer out of this formula. I would be happy to upvote it.

@JeanMarie: Done!

Preamble: We basically take the converse of their fifth method.
For elementary geometry purists, if you didn't like how they used Stewart's theorem with Cosine rule trigo at the start (hence at my end), I've provided an alternative ending using the converse of OP's method (which is their third method).
Solution: Let the side lengths of $ ABC$ be $a, b, c, $ as usual.
By angle bisector theorem, $BC_1  = \frac{ ac}{a+b} $.
Through $C$, construct a line $ \ell$ that is parallel to $AB$.
Let $C_1 B_1$ intersect $\ell$ at $D$, and $C_1 A_1$ intersect $\ell$ at $E$.
Since $CEA_1$ is similar to $BC_1 A_1$, hence $ \frac{ CE} { BC1} = \frac{ CA_1 } { A_1 B} = \frac{ CA}{AB} = \frac{ b}{c} $.
Thus $CE = \frac{ab}{a+b}$.
Likewise, $CD = \frac{ab}{a+b}$, so $C$ is the midpoint of the hypotenuse of right triangle $C_1 DE$. Hence $C_1 C$ is the median, also of length $ \frac{ab}{a+b}$.
Using Stewart's theorem, $C_1 C = \frac{ 2CA \cdot CB } { CA + CCB } \cos \angle ACB$, hence $ \angle ACB = 120 ^ \circ$.
Alternative ending:
Since $C$ is the midpoint of the hypotenuse, so $CDC_1$ is an isosceles triangle, and thus $\angle CC_1 D =  \angle CDC_1 = \angle DC_1 A$, which shows that $C_1 D$ is the angle bisector of $\angle CC_1 A$. Likewise, $C_1E$ is the angle bisector of $\angle CC_1 B$.
In triangle $BC_1 C$, $B_1$ is the intersection of the internal angle bisector at $B$ and the external angle bisector at $C_1$, hence is the excenter. Thus, $CB_1$ is the external angle bisector at $C$.
Likewise, $CA_1$ is the external angle bisector at $C$ for triangle $AC_1C$.
Thus, $\angle ACB = 120^\circ.$
Their image, with different notation than in this problem.
$A \leftrightarrow C,   L_1 \rightarrow C_1, L_2 \rightarrow B_1, L_3 \rightarrow A_1$

Note: While they claim that it's an original approach, I know I've seen this setup before.

This looks a known property. On page 9 (179) of this document, one finds :
Remark. The cevian triangle of the incenter contains a right angle if and only if the triangle contains an interior angle of 120◦ angle (see [1]).
[1] H. Demir, J. Oman: Problem 998. Math. Mag. 49, 252 (1976); solution 51, 199–200 (1978). (unfortunately, I haven't this issue)

@JeanMarie I've found the issue on jstor. One may have a read here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690005 (the proof of Problem 998 involves the law of cosines though)

@JeanMarie Definitely. I saw this problem more than 20 years ago when I was training for the math olympiads. When I saw that figure, I recalled that it allowed for an if and only if proof.

Converting a comment to an answer, by request ...

In $\triangle ABC$, let the bisectors of angles $A$, $B$, $C$ meet the opposite sides at $D$, $E$, $F$. Let the sides of $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DEF$ be $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$, $e$, $f$ in the standard arrangements.

The Angle Bisector Theorem yields expressions for the lengths of various sub-segments (eg, $b_A := |AE|=\dfrac{bc}{a+c}$), as shown in the figure. From here, we apply the Law of Cosines a few times, first to write $d^2$ in two ways, then to find $e$ and $f$, and then also to express $\cos A$, $\cos B$, and $\cos C$ in terms of the side lengths.
$$\begin{align}
e^2+f^2-2ef\cos D =d^2 &= b_A^2+c_A^2-2b_A c_A\cos A \\[2pt]
&= b_A^2+c_A^2-2b_Ac_A\cdot\frac{-a^2+b^2+c^2}{2bc}  \tag1\\[8pt]
e^2 &= c_B^2+a_B^2-2c_B a_B\cos B \\[2pt]
&= c_B^2+a_B^2-2c_Ba_B\cdot\frac{-b^2+c^2+a^2}{2ca} \\[2pt]
&= \frac{a^2 b^2 c^2\;(3 + 2\cos A - 2\cos B + 2\cos C)}{(a + b)^2 (b + c)^2} \tag2 \\[8pt]
f^2 &= a_C^2+b_C^2-2a_C b_C\cos C \\[2pt]
&= a_C^2+b_C^2-2a_C b_C\cdot\frac{-c^2+a^2+b^2}{2ab} \\[2pt]
&= \frac{a^2 b^2 c^2\;(3 + 2\cos A + 2 \cos B - 2 \cos C)}{(a + c)^2 (b + c)^2} \tag3
\end{align}$$
With these, and a symbol-manipulating assist from Mathematica, we find that $(1)$ ultimately reduces to
$$1 + 2\cos A = qr \cos D \tag4$$
where
$$\begin{align}
q^2 &:= 3 + 2\cos A - 2 \cos B + 2 \cos C \\[2pt]
&\,= 1 + 8 \cos\tfrac12A \sin\tfrac12B \cos\tfrac12C \\[8pt]
r^2 &:= 3 + 2\cos A + 2 \cos B - 2 \cos C \\[2pt]
&\,= 1 + 8 \cos\tfrac12A \cos\tfrac12B \sin\tfrac12C
\end{align} \tag5$$
as claimed. $\square$
